# preg_replace, insert hashtags around desired value

Tags: php, regex

So i have this string, it can look like this:

```
<div style="display:none">231</div>.<div style="display:none">13</div>
```

id want:

```
<div style="display:none">231</div>#.#<div style="display:none">13</div>
```

or like this:

```
<div style="display:none">231</div>125<div style="display:none">13</div>
```

where id want

```
<div style="display:none">231</div>#125#<div style="display:none">13</div>
```

id like a preg replace to put those hashtags around the numb, so i asume the REGEX would look something like this:

```
"<\/div>[.]|<\/div>\d{1,3}"
```

The digit (in case its a digit, can be 1-3 digits), or it can be a dot.

Anyhow, i dont know hot to preg replace around the value:

```
"<\/div>[.]|<\/div>\d{1,3}" replace: $0#
```

Inserts it after the value.

Answer (score 0):

tell me what you think about `assertions` in `Reqular Expression Syntax`

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$lookBehind = '\<div style\=\"display\:none\"\>231\<\/div\>';
$lookAhead = '\<div style\=\"display\:none\"\>13\<\/div\>';
$re = '~(?<='.$lookBehind.')(\.|\d+)(?='.$lookAhead.')~';
$str = '<div style="display:none">231</div>.<div style="display:none">13</div>';
echo preg_replace($re, '#$1#', $str).PHP_EOL;
$str = '<div style="display:none">231</div>125<div style="display:none">13</div>';
echo preg_replace($re, '#$1#', $str).PHP_EOL;
?>
```

`Lookahead` is `(?=)` and `Lookbehind` is `(?<=)`

whatever is inside the assertion parens does not become part of the substitution, consider it a *check* if you will.

PS: just tested it and it works, but someone might want to chime in with something with better performance. I'm no guru on this subject